# Instrumenting New Relic APM to a Node.js app on Azure Container App doesn't work

Tags: node.js, newrelic, azure-container-apps

I'm trying to instrument New Relic APM on a NodeJS app on Azure Container App, but was not able to get data on the New Relic dashboard. From the step-by-step guide on New Relic console, at first I tried to follow the Dockerfile approach where I install newrelic and add require('newrelic') to my app.js file, and add `ENV NEW_RELIC_NO_CONFIG_FILE=true`, however, deploying the container app doesn't require me to specify the `docker run..` command.

I also tried the "Installation on a host" approach, where I installed newrelic and tried running my app within the container with a npm start script like "NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME=app-name NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY=XXX node -r newrelic YOUR_MAIN_FILENAME.js" but that didn't work either, I also tried using newrelic.js in the root directory but nothing seems to work.

No matter what I did and how long I waited the APM dashboard would still be empty. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!
[image]